Power Apps Reference Table and Column to Variable
Is there a way in Power Apps to reference a collection and column to variable?
Set(MyCollectionC, MyTable1)
Set(MyCollectionColumn, MyColumn)

Collect(MyCollectionC, {ID: myId, MyColumn: FieldCombo.Selected.MyCollectionColumn });


You can set a table to a collection, but not reference a column from a variable name. Power Apps is a strongly-typed language: every expression has a well-defined type. For example,
{ ID: myId, MyColumn: 1 }

Defines a record with two columns, one called 'ID' that has the same type as myId (which is defined elsewhere in the app), and one called 'MyColumn' of type number.
Using something like FieldCombo.Selected.MyVariableWithTheColumnName breaks this assumption, so it cannot be used.
If the possible types of the columns are the same, then you can use something like the expression below:
Collect(
  MyCollectionC,
  {
    ID: myId,
    MyColumn: Switch(myCollectionColumn,
      "PossibleColumn1", FieldCombo.Selected.PossibleColumn1,
      "PossibleColumn1", FieldCombo.Selected.PossibleColumn2,
      "PossibleColumn3", FieldCombo.Selected.PossibleColumn3
      // An optional value if myCollectionColumn doesn't match any of the columns
    )
  }
);

